# Does $match in mongoose match inside an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, match

I'm going through some code left by a previous developer, and came across this:

```
 const distinctDocumentAggregate = await SSProductModel.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: "$styleID", doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" } } },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$doc" } },
  { $match: { "warehouses.closeout": false } },
  ...
```

Assuming the document looks like this (omitting irrelevant fields):

```
{
   _id: 1880409,
   warehouses: [
    {
        skuID: 1880411,
        qty: 45,
        closeout: false,
        fullCaseOnly: false,
        returnable: true,
        expectedInventory: 'EnRoute:None|OnOrder:TBD-24'
    },
    {
        skuID: 1880412,
        qty: 0,
        fullCaseOnly: false,
        closeout: true,
        returnable: true,
        expectedInventory: 'EnRoute:None|OnOrder:TBD-48'
    },
    {
        skuID: 1880414,
        qty: 24,
        fullCaseOnly: false,
        returnable: true,
        expectedInventory: 'EnRoute:None|OnOrder:None'
    }
  ]
}
```

Is the match query valid here? Is mongoose smart enough to go through the array of warehouses and match check if their *closeout* parameter is false?

Additionally, what would happen if some of the warehouse objs didn't even have the closeout variable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you try it? the query looks good and valid, and if there is no `closeout` parameter, it will return nothing and/or an empty array.

Comment: anyway, [aggregate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) is also a query of `mongodb`. So yeah, `mongoose` is pretty smart